# jQuery datepicker resets input to today

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a text input where a user inputs a date of birth. They can either use the included jQuery datepicker, or they can enter it themselves in mmddyy, mm/dd/yy, or mm-dd-yy formats, with either 2- or 4-digit years. I convert their format to mm/dd/yyyy manually.

My current code works so far, as long as the user doesn't press enter. If they do, and the box has a format other than mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yyyy, the datepicker changes the value to today's date. Is there a way I could keep the datepicker from overwriting the date like this?

Here is my JS code for the whole thing:

```
var datebox = $('#applicant_dob');

datebox.datepicker({
    constrainInput: false,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    showOn: "focus",
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    showOptions: { direction: "down" },
    onClose: function(e, c) {
        var d = $(this);
        datepickerOnClose(e, d);
    }
});

function datepickerOnClose(e, d){
    var changeFlag = true;
    if(/^(\d{2})[\/](\d{2})[\/](\d{4})$/.test(e)){
        changeFlag = false;
    }
    //change yy to yyyy if needed
    //(assumes date is in mmddyy, mm/dd/yy, or mm-dd-yy format
    if(/^(\d{2})[\/-]?(\d{2})[\/-]?(\d{2})$/.test(e)){
        var yy = e.substr(e.length - 2, 2);
        var yyyy = yy >= 15 ? 19 + yy : 20 + yy; 
        e = e.substring(0, e.length - 2) + yyyy;
        d.val(e);
    }

    //convert to mm/dd/yyyy
    if(/^\d{8}$/.test(e)){
        d.val(e.slice(0, 2) + '/' + e.slice(2, 4) + '/' + e.slice(4, 8));
        changeFlag = true;
    }else{
        if(/^(\d{4})[\/-](\d{2})[\/-](\d{2})$/.test(e)){
            d.val(e.replace(/^(\d{4})[\/-](\d{2})[\/-](\d{2})$/, "$2/$3/$1"));
            changeFlag = true;
        }else{
            if(/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/.test(e)){
                d.val(e.replace(/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/, "$1/$2/$3"));
                changeFlag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(changeFlag){
        d.change();
    }
}

datebox.on('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){ //'enter' key
        console.log('fired');
        datepickerOnClose($(elm).val(), $(elm));
        $(elm).focusout();
    }
});
```

**EDITS:**

1. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/41yr3y3n/6/ (try entering 101010 for an example, goal is to autocorrect it to 10/10/2010)
2. I should mention that this only happens once, after you enter a date for the first time. It works fine after that until you refresh.

Comment: 404 jsfiddle not found, please create one\

Comment: Alright, I'll get one set up. It may take a bit; I've never used jsfiddle, and all of this hooks into a much larger application with a lot of moving parts, so it's hard to figure out what I need and what I don't.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/41yr3y3n/3/

Comment: `elm` is undefined. Check your browser console.

Comment: My mistake. Check edits for the new jsfiddle link.

Comment: Found this datepicker BUG in the current versions. You can see it in action with the "all defaults" canonical demo at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ if you type a date with a ONE, TWO, or THREE digit year, and then [Enter]. It doesn't happen for blur by click-outside or tab. And it doesn't KEEP happening; once the date has reverted to today's 4-digit year, the input will retain a 1, 2 or 3 digit year upon [Enter]. To see it happen "just once" again, reload the page.